# What classes do <T> and <U> represent in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been reading the [Angular 2 TypeScript docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api) and I am running into a lot of these two classes. Would someone please expound on what they are?

An example code from the [QueryList api](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/QueryList-class.html) docs is:

```
class QueryList {
    changes : Observable<any>
    length : number
    first : T
    last : T
    map(fn: (item: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U) : U[]
    filter(fn: (item: T, index: number, array: T[]) => boolean) : T[]
    reduce(fn: (prevValue: U, curValue: T, curIndex: number, array: T[]) =>      U, init: U) : U
    forEach(fn: (item: T, index: number, array: T[]) => void) : void
    some(fn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => boolean) : boolean
    toArray() : T[]
    toString() : string
    reset(res: Array<T|any[]>) : void
    notifyOnChanges() : void
    setDirty()
    dirty 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are Generics. They can represent any type:

[TypeScript - Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

It's simply a way to write a function that can take any type but still enforce that type throughout the function (whatever you chose for `T` has to remain a `T` the whole way through the function).

Comment: It seems like `T` is a type parameter to the generic class `QueryList`, but for some reason it is not shown in the API documentation.

Comment: And `U` should be the sole type parameter to the generic functions `map` and `reduce`, but again it is not shown.

Comment: So it's like the `any` type but can't take any other types after first assign? Then what about `U`?

Comment: @davejoem - Yes. And `U` is simply another generic parameter separate from `T`.